# Adding point symbol from subset onto line legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a very basic dataset that looks like:

```
data <- data.frame(Day  = c(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
              Treatment = c("C", "T","C", "T","C", "T","C", "T","C", "T","C","T"),
              Temp = c(10,10,10,12,10,14,10,16,10,18,10,20))
```

And a graph that looks like

```
ggplot(data, aes(Day, Temp, group = Treatment))+
  geom_line(linetype="dashed", linewidth = 1, position = position_dodge(width=1), aes(color = 
  Treatment))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("lightblue","darkred"))+
  geom_point(data = subset(data, Day %in% c("0","3","5")), shape = 1, 
  size = 3, color = "gray32")+
  labs(y = expression(paste("Temperature [", degree, "C]")), x = "Experimental Day")+
  theme_bw()
```

The subsetted points I added are measurement days in my experiment (I know on my reprex the points aren't on the line I'm not sure why - they are in my actual plot), I was just wondering if anyone knows how to add the point symbol and label onto my plot legend? I would like the legend to have the title "legend" and then the dashed lines labelled as "control" and "treatment" and the symbol as "measurement day".

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(Day, Temp, group = Treatment)) +
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed", linewidth = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 1), aes(color = Treatment)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("lightblue", "darkred"), labels = c("Control", "Treatment")) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Day %in% c("0", "3", "5")), size = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  labs(y = expression(paste("Temperature [", degree, "C]")), x = "Experimental Day") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(NA, 1), labels = c("", "Measurement Day"), name = "")
```

[image: plot]